# How to call JavaScript function in Razor

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, model-view-controller

I've created an array and pass it to view with ViewBag.

```
ViewBag.MarkerList = Utility.markerList;
```

And I have a function to add a marker on map in JavaScript:

```
function myFunction(item) {
    var marker = L.marker([item.lat, item.lng], { riseOnHover: true }).addTo(mymap);
    marker.bindPopup("I am a popup.<br>"+ item.lat + "," + item.lng);
}
var array = @ViewBag.MarkerList;

        array.foreach(myFunction);
```

How can I use foreach in ViewBag and call the JavaScript function?

Comment: where do you want to call this function? on page load or on a button/link click?

Comment: Razor doesn't execute JavaScript. Razor (potentially) outputs JavaScript that the browser eventually runs.

Comment: @Pio in page load

Comment: @ARM4N8 What does your JavaScript look like when you click 'View Page Source' in a browser? This may give you a clue.

Comment: Pre-format the markerList as a string and put it in a ViewBag. I assume that you have `List<string>`. So ac ode will look like this: `List<string> l = new List<string> { "Saab", "Volvo", "BMW" };

      string strOutput = "[";

      l.ForEach(x => strOutput += String.Format("\"{0}\",", x));

      strOutput = strOutput.Substring(0, strOutput.Length - 1);

      strOutput += "]"; ViewBag.MarkerList = strOutput;`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert c# array to json for javascript in method and call method on page load.

```
function myFunction() {
    var markerList= @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag.MarkerList));
    for(item in markerList) {
        var marker = L.marker([item.lat, item.lng], { riseOnHover: true}).addTo(mymap);
        marker.bindPopup("I am a popup.<br>"+ item.lat + "," + item.lng);
    }
}
```

Comment: there is an error !
json does not contain a definition for serialize

Comment: He probably meant to say `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(...`. You'll need an `@using` for Newtonsoft.